# Realm React Native - Migration is required: Target type 'string' doesn't exist for property 'emailAddresses'

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I am building a small app with React Native and want to use [Realm](http://www.realm.io) for persistency.

I defined the following schema for a `Person`:

```
const personSchema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    familyName: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    givenName: {type: 'string'},
    middleName: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    emailAddresses: {type: 'list', objectType: 'string'},
  }
}
export class Person {}
Person.schema = personSchema
```

The information as to how a Realm schema needs to be defined can be found in the [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/).

I then instantiate the DB like so:

```
const schemas = [Person]
const db = new Realm({schema: schemas})
```

However, there is an exception when reaching the last line giving me the following error:

> Unhandled JS Exception: Migration is required due to the following
>   errors:
>
> - Target type `string` doesn't exist for property `emailAddresses`.

I am using the iOS simulator for testing and deleted the app several times and then reinstalled it using the play button in Xcode.

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this exception?

#### Update

I now created a separate schema for another db object: `EmailAdress`

```
const emailAddressSchema = {
  name: 'EmailAddress',
  properties: {
    label: 'string',
    email: 'string'
  }
}
export class EmailAddress {}
EmailAddress.schema = emailAddressSchema
```

I also changed the `objectType` of `emailAddresses` in the `personSchema` to be of type `EmailAddress` now:

```
...
emailAddresses: {type: 'list', objectType: 'EmailAddress'},
...
```

Now, I am not getting the exception any more. Isn't it possible to add a property to a Realm class that is a list of `string`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists of primitives are not yet supported in Realm. Until they are you need to wrap primitive types in an object as you have done with `EmailAddress`